# Mongoose query for docs matching array, no matter its elements order

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Using MongoDB/Mongoose, consider my `test` collection having the following 2 documents:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5c4e3cef9cd12904cfc7ecc0"),
"name" : "REGISTER1",
"properties" : [
        {
            "property” : "PROP1",
            "value" : "GREEN"
        },
        {
            "property” : "PROP2",
            "value" : "RED"
        }
    ]
```

and

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5c4e3cef9cd12904cfc7ecc0"),
"name" : "REGISTER2",
"properties" : [
        {
            "property" : "PROP2",
            "value" : "RED"
        },
        {
            "property" : "PROP1",
            "value" : "GREEN"
        }
    ]
```

I'm using the folowing commands to find the registers:

```
db.tests.find(
   { properties: [
            {
                "property" : "PROP2",
                "value" : "RED"
            },
            {
                "property" : "PROP1",
                "value" : "GREEN"
            }
        ]
   }).pretty();
```

That returns `REGISTER2`, not `REGISTER1`.

In the same way:

```
db.tests.find(
   { properties: [
            {
                "property" : "PROP1",
                "value" : "GREEN"
            },
            {
                "property" : "PROP2",
                "value" : "RED"
            }
        ]
   }).pretty();
```

That returns `REGISTER1`, not `REGISTER2`.

I need both queries to return both elements 'REGISTER1' and 'REGISTER2', as the only change between then is the properties order (the array order).

How can I query to return both `REGISTER1` and `REGISTER2`, no matter the array order of the query elements ?

Comment: on your first document the key is `property_id` and on second document property key is `property`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#op._S_all) query for this:

```
db.tests.find({
  properties: {$all: [
   {property: 'PROP1', value: 'GREEN'},
   {property: 'PROP2', value: 'RED'} 
]}})
```

Both elements of the `$all` have to exist for the document to match, but the order is irrelevant.

For the case where `properties` elements contain more keys besides what you're matching on, you can use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch):

```
db.tests.find({
  properties: {$all: [
   {$elemMatch: {property: 'PROP1', value: 'GREEN'}},
   {$elemMatch: {property: 'PROP2', value: 'RED'}} 
]}})
```

`$elemMatch` ensures each `property`/`value` tuple matches the same element.

Comment: The 2nd piece of code is the exact answer I am looking for... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The property name on first document is `property_id` and second document is `property`

Please use `$elemMatch` with `$or` to get both the matching documents

```
db.tests.find({
    properties : {$elemMatch : {$or : [
        {"property" : "PROP1", "value" : "GREEN"},
        {"property" : "PROP2", "value" : "RED"}
    ]}}
})
```

sample collection

```
> db.tests.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c4e3cef9cd12904cfc7ecc0"), "name" : "REGISTER1", "properties" : [ { "property" : "PROP1", "value" : "GREEN" }, { "property" : "PROP2", "value" : "RED" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c4e3cef9cd12904cfc7ecc1"), "name" : "REGISTER2", "properties" : [ { "property" : "PROP2", "value" : "RED" }, { "property" : "PROP1", "value" : "GREEN" } ] }
```

find

```
> db.tests.find({properties : {$elemMatch : {$or : [{"property" : "PROP1", "value" : "GREEN"},{"property" : "PROP2", "value" : "RED"}]}}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c4e3cef9cd12904cfc7ecc0"), "name" : "REGISTER1", "properties" : [ { "property" : "PROP1", "value" : "GREEN" }, { "property" : "PROP2", "value" : "RED" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c4e3cef9cd12904cfc7ecc1"), "name" : "REGISTER2", "properties" : [ { "property" : "PROP2", "value" : "RED" }, { "property" : "PROP1", "value" : "GREEN" } ] }
>
```

Comment: That seems to return registers that has PROP1 *OR* PROP2 ser, that is not the case. I need both of them set in any order....

Comment: I have updated answer with the output, can you post the expected output?